# Cakephp 3 Bake all issue with MSSQLSRV

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cakephp 3 and MSSQLSRV 2014. I made all the necessary changes to connect to MSSQL server. In GUI, I can see that cakephp can connect to MSSQL. Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

So now when I go to bin directory to bake the application, I get below error unable to load MSSQL driver, which is already installed:

[image]

Here are my datasource settings in app.php file:

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS',
            /**
             * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
             * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
             * the following line and set the port accordingly
             */
            'port' => '1433',
            'username' => 'sa',
            'password' => 'password',
            'database' => 'ServerMatrix',
            'encoding' => 65001,
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,
```

I am thinking its probably a bug that should be reported to CakePHP community, but wanted to get some help from stack-overflow community to see if they have encountered such issue.

Comment: The webserver and the CLI do not neccessarily use the same PHP configuration. Check for a possible CLI related `php.ini` and configure it appropriately (ie make sure that the driver is being included/enabled).

Comment: @ndm - the extensions are enabled in php.ini file. shouldn't cli automatically grab the configuration automatically? Here are the two extensions that are in php.ini `extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`

Comment: As I said, not necessarily, the CLI might use its own `php.ini` (check `php --ini`).

Comment: @ndm - You are awesome. Yes, it looks like the extension was missing in cli `php-ini` file. I added it and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In command line interface typed `php --ini` and opened loaded php.ini file and added SQLSrv extensions. That solved the problem for baking an application.

Thanks to @ndm.